# null empty set has 2 subsets?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

The question in the book was:

How many subsets does $\{\emptyset\}$ have?

a) 0,
 b) 1,
 c) 2,
 d) 3.

The answer was c. How can an empty set have 2 subsets?

Comment: An empty set has only $1$ subset, but $\{\emptyset\}$ is not an empty set. A one-element set $\{a\}$ has $2$ subsets, regardless of what its single element $a$ may be; in this case, $a=\emptyset.$

Comment: Because $\{ ∅ \}$ is **not** the *empty set*; the empty set is $\{ \} = \emptyset$. The set $\{ ∅ \}$ is not empty; it has **one** element : the set $\emptyset$.

Comment: Elaborating on the previous comment, the subsets of {$\emptyset$} are $\emptyset$ and {$\emptyset$}.

Answer (score 2):

The subsets of $\{a\}$ are $\{\}=\varnothing$ and $\{a\}$, no matter what $a$ is. Here, we simply have $a=\varnothing$.

On the other hand, if the question asked you for the subsets of $\varnothing$, you'd only have one subset.

> REMEMBER THAT $\{\varnothing\}\ne\varnothing$!!